# How to exclude string that begin with a character

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

I am using regex to match

```
([A-Za-z2-7\/\\+]{52})
```

While any string with 52 characters as the one mentioned above will match the string, I want to exclude strings that begin with : followed by the 52 characters.

I am using regex flavor pcre2
For example while the below string matches the regex I wouldn't want to include it since the 52 characters preceed with a :

```
C:\Users\abcdef\AppData\Local\abcdefghijklmnopqr\Testmeli_fi
```

Comment: If I use your pattern `([A-Za-z2-7\/\\+]{52})` for `C:\Users\abcdef\AppData\Local\abcdefghijklmnopqr\Testmeli_fi` string, it only selects 52 characters: `\Users\abcdef\AppData\Local\abcdefghijklmnopqr\Testm`. So if this deleted, result will be `C:eli_fi`. Is it what you want?

Comment: Use a negative lookbehind.

Comment: If you exclude a string preceded by `:`, it will just match that string starting from the `U` instead of `\ `.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```php
:([A-Za-z2-7\/\\+]{52})(*SKIP)(*F)|(?1)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/PeHLxs/2).

**EXPLANATION**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Za-z2-                 any character of: 'A' to 'Z', 'a' to
    7\/\\+]{52}              'z', '2' to '7', '\/', '\\', '+' (52
                             times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (*SKIP)(*F)              fail the match and restart after failure
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |                        or
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?1)                       recurse group 1 pattern
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use an anchor to assert the start of the string:

```
^[A-Za-z2-7\/\\+]{52}
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1Rit19/1).